# Force of interest :$e^{\int_0^t{\delta_t}ds}$ vs $(1+\frac{i^{(2)}}{2})^2$

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I was wondering if someone could help me confirm the answer for the following problem regarding force of interest.

> X deposits $1$ at time $t=0$ with force of interest $\delta_t=\frac{t^2}{k}$.  Y deposits the same amount at the same time with nominal interest of $8\%$ per annum convertible semi annually. At $t=5$, their accumulated values are equal.  What is $k$?

I have two questions.

1), "nominal interest of $8\%$ per annum convertible semiannually"

What does this mean?  I want to say that interest is compounded $8\%$ per year so

$$(1+ \frac{i^{(2)}}{2})^2=1.08$$

But could it mean

$$i^{(2)}=8\%$$

?

If that is not the case, how do you describe the other case?

2), I tried the calculation by

$$\exp \left[ {\int_0^5\frac{t^2}{k}dt} \right] =(1.08)^5$$

which yields

$$k=\frac{125}{15 \ln (1.08)}$$

The book tells me the answer is $102$, which I think is not an approximation deviation.

Can someone explain me what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result you have to use this definition of future value:

$FV_n=\frac{\text{DPV}}{(1-i)^n}$

DPV: Discounted present value

You have semi anually intervals. Thus the formula is

$FV_{5}=\frac{\text{1}}{(1-\frac{i}{2})^{5\cdot 2}}=\frac{\text{1}}{(1-\frac{0.08}{2})^{10}}$

Hence the equation is: $$\large{e^{\int_0^5 x^2/k}=\frac{1}{(1-0.04)^{10}}}$$

$\int_0^5 x^2/k=ln \left( \frac{1}{(1-0.04)^{10}} \right)$

$\frac{125}{3k}=-10*ln(0.96)$

$\frac{1}{k}=-\frac{30}{125}\cdot ln \left( 0.96 \right)$

$\Rightarrow k=-\frac{125}{30\cdot ln(0.96)}\approx 102$

Comment: Hmm... I am confused.  Why are you using $i$ as if it is a discounted rate?

Comment: You know what, I re-read the problem and it was "discount rate of $8\%$".   Under that condition your calculation is exactly what it's supposed to do.  Thank you.  However, how did you actually solve this problem without knowing that?  Did you just try it out and it worked out?

Comment: @hyg17 I just tried it out.